# UIAlertView, once the user opens the app. Shown once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want a `UIAlertView` to show, once the user opens the app. It'll ask them for their email address. But i want it to only show once. So when the user re opens the app the uialertview shouldnt pop up. And the `UIAlertView` will contain 2 buttons within that. 'Dismiss' & 'Yes' .. the dismiss button will continue with the app. But the 'Yes' will take them to another view'.

Thanks :)
Edit:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alert"]]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"alert"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your email" 
                                                     message:@"\n\n\n" 
                                                    delegate:nil 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [textField setPlaceholder:@"enter email here"];
    [prompt addSubview:textField];



    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];


    //[textField becomeFirstResponder];

}
}
```

Okay this is the code at the moment, im stuck on how the email is going to be sent to be once the user presses enter.

Comment: Why do you need an alert?  Just take them to the view to enter the email address if you don't have it already.  Provide a cancel button on that view if they don't want to enter it.

Comment: because alerts 'engages' the user, its straight foward, the user wont have to seach for the email view

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to save a `boolean` between sessions.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
// save 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"hasRunBefore"];

// load 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"hasRunBefore"] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the email address in NSUserDefaults (I guess you are already doing it, if you ask for it only the very first time your app starts); each time the app starts, you check if the email address is there (NSUserDefaults); if not, you display the UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

First, need to make yourself the delegate for the UIAlertView so you know when the user has pressed Cancel or Enter. So this:

```
UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your email" 
                                                 message:@"\n\n\n" 
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
```

The delegate callback is this method:

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Once that's called, you can retrieve the email address from the textField instance you created and added to the alert view.