# uialertview in login page in every launch

Tags: iphone, ios5, uialertview, appdelegate

I have an alertview to show the update of new version in the login page (1st page). But Actually i want this alert to come only in the login page every time it launches .
 i have seen so many question related to this but none helped some of them are [Displaying an alert message only ONCE but to reappear again on app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083067/displaying-an-alert-message-only-once-but-to-reappear-again-on-app-launch)

[UIAlertView, once the user opens the app. Shown once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945300/uialertview-once-the-user-opens-the-app-shown-once)
 .......

Now my code is

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(getUpdate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

in **DidBecomeActive** method. We are calling Webservice to get the update alertmsg.

and my problem is

1) By using the code in DidBecomeActive,For the 1st time it works gud after closing without logout and whenever we reopen the app, the alert comes in current page no matters 1st or last.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is that you call a method in your view controller from your app delegate.

In your `appdelegate.m` file you will have a method called `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions...` in here will be some code which instantiates the view and calls the first view controller.

For instance I have just started a new project (Master Detail Application - but yours will be similar).

There is some code in my `AppDelegate.m` file that looks like this:

```
    PMXMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[PMXMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PMXMasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    masterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

What this does is `init` the view controller, add it to the navigation controller and set the managedObjectContext variable.

After this you can call any methods on your view controller:

`[masterViewController showAlertDialog:@"My Message Here"]`

In `masterViewController` you need to make a method called `showAlertDialog`:

```
- (void)showAlertDialog:(NSString *)message {
    // show alert dialog here
}
```

As the app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLauching...` method will only get called when the app starts that means that your alert dialog will only show when the app starts!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess that u need to display the alert only the first time when the application launches... if that is so... try this method

To determine whether its the first run in the appdidfinishlaunching method

store a bool in nsuserdefaults like firstRun

```
if([defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]==nil)
{
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"firstRun"];
}
else
{
[defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"firstRun"];
}
```

and then later when u display the alert display it only when this value is YES

Comment: not only for the 1st time . when i logged out and reopen it should come .

Comment: ok then modify the above process as to set the BOOL loggedIn to YES when you sign in and NO when you logout.... and display the alert only when the loggedIn variable is NO

Answer (score -1):

Write following code in the viewDidLoad method of your concerned view controller:

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UNLOCK PIN!"
                                                      message:@"Enter your valid PIN."
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

message.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;

[message show];
```